# Rotate Binary Tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I am trying to print a non static binary tree.
It does print but it rotates towards the left. I cant find a way to correct this and make it rotate upright. 5 is the root node. Code:

```
template <class dataType>
void displaybinarytree(BinaryTree <dataType> * p, int indent)
{
if(p != NULL) {
    if(p->right()) {
        displaybinarytree(p->right(), indent+4);
    }

    if (indent) {
        cout << setw(indent) << ' ';
    }

    if (p->right()){
        cout<<" /\n" << setw(indent) << ' ';
    }

    cout<< p->getData() << "\n ";

    if(p->left()) {
        cout << setw(indent) << ' ' <<" \\\n";
        displaybinarytree(p->left(), indent+4);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: Rather than images showing the actual and expected output, please enter them as text (specifically as fixed width text by prefixing with four spaces).

Comment: Thanks for the expected output, but we still need a [mcve], that is the code you run that produces the output in the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive approach doesn't play nice with a line-based output, where a line consists of items from multiple sub-trees.

You should switch to a breadth-first-traversal, where you create a working set per tree level. You may need to pre-compute the space requirements of lower tree levels in order to output the desired alignments in higher levels.

A little starting code that doesn't really display the tree as a tree, but at least displays each node in the correct line.

```
void displaybinarytree(BinaryTree <int> * p, int indent)
{
    deque<BinaryTree<int>*> current;
    deque<BinaryTree<int>*> next;
    next.push_back(p);

    while (!next.empty())
    {
        current.swap(next);
        while  (!current.empty())
        {
            BinaryTree<int>* node = current.front();
            current.pop_front();
            if (node->left)
            {
                next.push_back(node->left);
            }
            if (node->right)
            {
                next.push_back(node->right);
            }
            // instead of a single space, appropriate spacing is needed
            cout << " " << node->data;
        }
        // instead of a single newline, appropriate spacing and connector characters / \ are needed
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

See the in-code-comments for things that are missing from this code. I replaced your `dataType` by `int` and used primitive fields instead of getter functions, since it doesn't really matter to the concept.

Comment: The easier option is to ignore the (presumably typeset) example image and just double the spacing each level

Answer (score -1):

If you want the top of the tree to appear at the top of the output, you must output it first - before its branches.

Your code outputs the right branch first, and it therefore appears at the top of the output:

```
// Outputs right branch:
if(p->right()) {
    displaybinarytree(p->right(), indent+4);
}

if (indent) {
    cout << setw(indent) << ' ';
}

if (p->right()){
    cout<<" /\n" << setw(indent) << ' ';
}

// Outputs "current" node:
cout<< p->getData() << "\n ";
```

You need to switch the order: output the current node, then the branches.

Also, the slashes are in the wrong direction, and the indent changes need to be corrected. The left branch should be indented *less* rather than more.

Making just these changes at least gets the tree printed "top down". You will still find the branches are not printed next to each other - that requires a significantly more complex solution.

Comment: This is wrong.  It's more complex than that.  You need to print the left and right branches *at the same time*!  11, 13, and 4 need to be printed on the same line.

Comment: I don't understand.  The image for "expected output" shows the branches printed side by side.  This is *exactly* the problem the OP is having.

Comment: @MartinBonner it's not wrong, just not a complete solution. Added a comment at the bottom to mention that.

Comment: The OP currently has 11, 13, 4 in a line (vertical, rather than the desired horizontal).  Your code will not leave them in a line.  It's only "rotated" if you squint very hard at it.

Comment: @MartinBonner OP asks specifically about the rotated tree. The root in his output is at the left, not at the top, and its children are to the right of it, not (except for the left child) below it. My answer explains why. I have explained how to put the root at the top and the branches below it and to the correct side. Printing the branches side-by-side on the same lines would be the next step in the solution, but this answer addresses the written question (about the rotated tree) and I feel it is useful.